# Connect microcontroller with display (Parallalax with Black Swift + Python)

Tags: python, microcontroller

I am trying to connect the Black Swift with an display from Parallalax[1]. I have been reading lots of tutorials about that but with the displays being used on the tutorials there is always a difference to the pins on my display. The displays that are being used usually have lots of pins where you can choose the ones you need, but the display I have just has 3 pins (5V, GND, RX). Now I assume that with this RX pin I can control the display (like when I use lots of pins on other displays). But I dont know where to connect that RX pin on my Black Swift. The next thing is,

I have also read the manual on that display I have (the link I provided) but the examples they use there are all built up on some boards that are being sold on the website (for example nothing about how to connect a raspberry or arduino). When reading a tutorial everything seems pretty easy, but I guess I didnt choose my hardware wisely :(

Now my question, since I am new to this, is it possible to connect that display to some random microcontroller (in my case Black Swift) ? If yes, where should I connect that RX pin? What is this RX pin doing, (didnt find anything in the manual about that)? Since they are using some special way (PBasic?) to control the display (is inside the manual), is it be possible to control the display with pythong?

Thanks for the help

EDIT:

So far I have managed to turn on/off the UART mode, and it seems that this is not the issue bcz I am getting same results (weired characters on te display).

[1] https://www.parallax.com/sites/default/files/downloads/27979-Parallax-Serial-LCDs-Product-Guide-v3.1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The linked PDF tells the story pretty conclusively. You need a UART from your controller with the matching bps-rate as set up by the DIP-switches.

Following http://www.black-swift.com/wiki/index.php/File:BlackSwift-1.0-pinout.png you should connect GPIO10/UART_TX to the RX, and then program your uC in whatever language it supports.

Comment: Thanks deets. Black Swift supports python but how I am going to access the serial display through it? As I said, al tutorials I found access a parallel lcd display (access through GPIO pins but I dont have those)

Comment: You use the python serial module and send the control commands as specified in the PDF.

Comment: I searched on the datasheet and it says following in the interfaces section:1×16550 UART
but on the display i can choose: 2400, 9600, 19.200. So i assume i can use 9200 because my controller supports not more

Comment: 16550 is Not a bps but an IC identifier. It's a general purpose UART that supports e.g  19200. And probably a lot of others. So no worries.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I have tried to start the display (connected to the controller) without the data transfer (so no connection to GPIO10/UART_TX) and the screen seems to start normal (the cursor is in the top left position). But when i connect it to the GPIO/UART_TX i get random characters on it that are changing with time (it doesnt seem right :( )

Comment: hmm, i tried to connect it to a raspberry and there it works fine when I use the UART_TX pin. Obviously black swift doenst allow multiple usage of a pin, I guess I have to change it somewhere to UART_TX (or smt like that)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "multiple usage". One pin can only do one thing at a time (under normal circumstances). It needs proper setup of course.

Comment: I mean that the bord itself configures the pin properly(or it recognizes what it should do). As I said, the raspberry worked out of the box by just connecting to the GPIO15/UART_TX pin (or maybe default usage of that pin fits my usage and it was luck).

Comment: AFAIK the PI is set up by default as UART on the respective PIN - to allow a connection/debugging the system. Black swift - no idea how that beast works.